# Will a lower resistance potentiometer improve a panel meter scale reading?

Tags: analog, potentiometer, meter

I have an analogue tacho/RPM panel meter on an auto distributor tester, c1950s. This is not the original meter. It has two scales 0 - 6000 rpm and 0 - 1000 rpm, with a toggle switch between the two. When running, the max rpm on the scale I can get is 2000 rpm, no matter how fast the disc spins, the meter will not go past this mark. I have removed the meter and fitted it to a similar machine where it works perfectly.

There is a 500 ohm linear potentiometer in the circuit, which I can adjust the needle up or down, but not past the 2000 rpm mark. I tried a 2000 ohm pot I had, the needle would only move up to 3 - 400 rpm on the scale. This meter was changed by a previous owner at some point, but the pot appears to be original.

I do not have a circuit diagram, have changed out all capacitors, disconnected resistors and tested according to colour bands. So, if I were to fit say a 100 or 150 ohm pot, would this allow the needle to swing further across the scale. I use a digital laser meter to check the disk speed against the meter reading, up to 2000 rpm is appears to be accurate. I’m a novice so any advice is appreciated, thanks.

Thanks for your response Transistor. The meter is a moving coil type, I have no Written information of the unit. It is an Allen Syncrograph, model E137, distributor Tester. I have everything else functioning apart from the tacho meter. Given a higher resistance pot would not read much on the meter scale, I thought perhaps a lower resistance pot would read higher on the scale. I appreciate any comments, thanks

Thanks for response Reroute. Attached are images, the circuit board is attached to the two terminals on the back of the meter. The three terminals on the POT are connected, I will check which resistance gets the higher reading on the scale.
The other unit model E-319 the meter works on, uses a 6vdc car battery to operate the gauges, with a POT to SET the needle to the RH side of the meter scale before using. 240vac to run the motor.
This unit E-137 is 240vac, no battery.

[image: Allen E-137]
[image: RPM Meter]
[image: Circuit board]

Comment: We have no idea what the principle of operation of your meter is, no photo and no schematic. To tell you what's going happen if you change a pot would be a pointless guess.

Comment: Please start with a photo of the tacho and the pcb if you have the option, next up would be does the 2000RPM limit get reached when there is the highest resistance across the potentiometer leads or the lowest. many of the older frequency to voltage converter circuits used a potentiometer to set the amount of current, with the lower value meaning more current, as your not able to get higher, that seems like the wrong approach, instead it may be the supply voltage to the gauge is too low compared to the other system where it works (I repair this stuff daily)